Deeplinks doesn't open from browser on Android 10
I thought this should be very simple, but it just doesn't work.
The Manifest is
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ui.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />

            <data android:host="dev-something-frontend.test.mycompany.ru" />
        </intent-filter> 

Keep in mind I don't need assetlinks.json for android 10
when I open dev-something-frontend.test.mycompany.ru it still opens in a browser
